# Why is my responsive theme gets cut off in half on mobile devices?

Tags: wordpress

I've just finished a website using a responsive theme.  It is responsive on browsers but not on an actual mobile devices. Neither on Android nor iphone.  Yes, I have searched and played around with the meta tag of viewport but NO LUCKS!
Please help:  http://fitness.mobisitesepic.com
The website got cut off in half, it's only show the left side and does not shrink down.
Thanks,

Comment: There would be rather negative feedback on StackOverflow portal for questions, where links direct to sale promotions, instead of posting your actual code-related issue. **You may want to re-edit your post, so as not to violate the StackOverflow Netiquette.**

Comment: @user3666197 Not intending to insult, but if you redirect new users to a rule, ensure your spelling and grammar is faultless.

Comment: Thanks for a fair opinion. Considered it better, than facing a direct insultations from moderators, who just flag / put [on hold] without a word or without providing a reasonable time for any possible remedy :o)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add this meta to your website :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

But still work fine on my BlackBerry 10.